# font awesome unicode not displaying

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, icons, font-awesome

I have the following HTML code with Boostrap. I am trying to fill a list with Font Awesome icons 4.7.0. But it only shows the first icon and the others does not show them.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:9%">
  <div class="input-group-append" style="width: 40%;">
    <select class="form-control fa" name="selectableList">
      <option class="fa fa-search" value="0">&#xf002;</option>
      <option class="fa fa-equals" value="1">&#xf52c;</option>
      <option class="fa fa-not-equal" value="2">&#xf53e;</option>
      <option class="fa fa-spell-check" value="3">&#xf891;</option>
      <option class="fa fa-remove-format" value="4">&#xf87d;</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="textInput" />
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eliasvargasloyola/a76Lzu51/4/

What could be the problem?

Regards.

Comment: Try using font awesome 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Font Awesome 5`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-+N4/V/SbAFiW1MPBCXnfnP9QSN3+Keu+NlB+0ev/YKQ=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:9%">
  <div class="input-group-append" style="width: 40%;">
    <select class="form-control fa" name="selectableList">
      <option class="fa fa-search" value="0">&#xf002;</option>
      <option class="fa fa-equals" value="1">&#xf52c;</option>
      <option class="fa fa-not-equal" value="2">&#xf53e;</option>
      <option class="fa fa-spell-check" value="3">&#xf891;</option>
      <option class="fa fa-remove-format" value="4">&#xf87d;</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="textInput" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this font awesome link will help you:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:9%">
      <div class="input-group-append" style="width: 40%;">
        <select class="form-control fa" name="selectableList">
          <option class="fa fa-search" value="0">&#xf002;</option>
          <option class="fa fa-equals" value="1">&#xf52c;</option>
          <option class="fa fa-not-equal" value="2">&#xf53e;</option>
          <option class="fa fa-spell-check" value="3">&#xf891;</option>
          <option class="fa fa-remove-format" value="4">&#xf87d;</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="textInput" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers, indeed a solution is what [User863](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8053274/user863) propose.

If you cannot update the Font Awesome version, there is this alternative, using the [unicode symbols](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sm/list.htm).

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:9%">
  <div class="input-group-append" style="width: 35%;">
    <select class="form-control fa" name="searchTypeCampaing" style="font-size: 18px;font-family: Arial, FontAwesome;font-weight: bold;">
      <option class="fa fa-search" value="0">&#xf002</option>
      <option value="1">=</option>
      <option value="2">&#x2260;</option>
      <option value="3">&#x2208;</option>
      <option value="4">&#x2209;</option>
    </select>
  </div> <input class="form-control" name="campingTXT" type="text">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eliasvargasloyola/afx41zct/11/